# JSONObject surrounded by try-catch not working

Tags: java, php, android

I'm basically doing a login-registration android project. My registration is working well enough but my code inside try catch doesn't work. So the user registration can happen all the time when i click register button.

Below is my register function in java:

```
private void registerUser() {
        final String username = register_Username.getEditText().getText().toString();
        final String email = register_Email.getEditText().getText().toString();
        final String password = register_Password.getEditText().getText().toString();

        dialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
        dialog.show();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        dialog.dismiss();   
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);                        
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        dialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("username",username);
                        params.put("email",email);
                        params.put("password",password);
                        return params;
            }
        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Here is my php code for registration:

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/DBoperations.php';
$response=  array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $db_connect= new DBoperations();
        if ($db_connect->createUser($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email'])) {
            $response['error'] =false;
            $response['message']= "User registered successfully!";
        } else {
            $response['error'] =true;
            $response['message']= "User registered failed!";
        }       

    } else{
        $response['error'] =true;
        $response['message']= "Required fields are missing!";
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] =true;
    $response['message']= "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

The 'error' or the 'message' cant be Toasted. What should i do?

Comment: Try to put a logcat or show a Toast inside `catch` block.

Comment: DEBUG please at first.

Comment: Yes it is entering catch block.

Comment: so, the problem itself does not related to PHP ?

Comment: check the logcat for the exception you get.

Comment: In case you are not already, you should always validate the user input and use prepared statements instead of passing `$_POST` values directly within the query.

Comment: Print `response` to logcat, then see whether it's a valid JSON or not

Comment: "not working", or "not producing the result you expect"? these are two very different things. Do you get a Stacktrace?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What does the JSON from the server look like?

Comment: so: you don't have a json object, you just need to map a String to a json object?

Comment: Hmmm yea.... I'm kinda new to android and i was just following a tutorial. It works in tutorial. So what should i do next? I need to get a json object!

Comment: just add json_encode($response); in php file?

Comment: first check if your api is working by using a tool like postman, if its working then check if the response is a valid json. You would be able to convert the response into jsonobject only if the json is valid

Comment: it is working with postman.

Comment: what is the response shown in postman? please add it here

Comment: Yeah i fixed it... the response was   "Connected{"error":false,"message":"User registered successfully" i removed the echo from one of the functions

Comment: You can add answers i will upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of function JSON.parse() method to parse string into JSONObject. And then traverse to "message" data in your JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using trim() for getting the string from the fields.

```
final String username = register_Username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
final String email = register_Email.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
final String password = register_Password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
```

Hopefully this helps!